# Database Page Cache Error in Windows 8

Tags: windows

**Following error always comes in my windows 8 machine, because of this some times my machine get restarted, How can I fix this issue.**

---

svchost (1348) SRUJet: The database page read from the file "C:\Windows\system32\SRU\SRUDB.dat" at offset 606208 (0x0000000000094000) (database page 147 (0x93)) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes failed verification due to a page checksum mismatch.  The stored checksum was [0000000000000000] and the computed checksum was [000000932ef3cde9].  The read operation will fail with error -1018 (0xfffffc06).  If this condition persists then please restore the database from a previous backup.  This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.